# MATLAB error "You can not subscript a table using only one subscript error" when adding table in another table

Tags: matlab

As an example I'll give a dataset in the form of a table **PEOPLE**:

```
phone      name           address
_____      ____    ____________________
                   country city  street
                   _____   ____  ______
1111       "A"     "C1"    "CI1" "STR1"
2222       "B"     "C1"    "CI2" "STR2"
3333       "A"     "C3"    "CI3" "STR3"
4444       "C"     "C2"    "CI4" "STR4"
...        ...     ...     ...   ...
```

As you can see a person (here **A**) can have multiple phone numbers each bound to a different address (for simplicity we exclude the possibility of two phone numbers for the same address).

I want to create an array of structures **PERSON** with the following fields:

- name: the name of person (second column in **PEOPLE**)
- data: a table with all phone numbers and addresses (first and third column in **PEOPLE**) the person specified by *name* has

  ```
    PERSON
      |----name (single value)
      |----data--* (table)
                 |----phone
                 |----address--*
                               |--country
                               |--city
                               |--street
  ```

As you can see the structure of the original data is in its greater part preserved with the only exception being the extraction of the name of a person and adding it to another field of my **PERSON** structure.

My problem comes from the third column **address** (**using Matlab R2014a**):

```
Error using table/subsrefDot (line 117)
You can not subscript a table using only one subscript. Table
subscripting requires both row and variable subscripts.

Error in table/subsref (line 62)
[varargout{1:nargout}] = subsrefDot(t,s);
```

My code is (not optimal, still learning :)):

```
% main script
...
% extract unique names
PEOPLE_UNIQUE = unique (PEOPLE.name,'stable');
personList = []
for person = 1:size(PEOPLE_UNIQUE)
  personList = [personList, createNewPerson(PEOPLE_UNIQUE(person,:).name, PEOPLE)];
end

% function file createNewPerson.m
function PERSON = createNewPerson(name, dataset)
  personData = table(dataset.phone(strcmp(dataset.name,name)),dataTable.address(strcmp(dataset.name,name)),'VariableNames',{'phone','address'});
  userprofile = struct('name',name,'data', personData);  
end
```

I'm sure that the problem comes from the address because I have tested creating a **PERSON** structure with multiple other non-complex (as in containing sub-columns) cells and it's working.

---

**EDIT**

I have just found out that disassembling **address** and re-assembling it when constructing the new table that is stored in **PERSON** works:

```
personData = table(dataset.phone(strcmp(dataset.name,name)),table(dataTable.address.country(strcmp(dataset.name,name)),dataTable.address.city(strcmp(dataset.name,name)),dataTable.address.street(strcmp(dataset.name,name)),'VariableNames',{'country','city','street'}),'VariableNames',{'phone','address'});
```

This is however too tedious and I dare not imagine that Matlab is incapable of inserting tables within tables. If you can give me a shortcut where I don't have to dissect **address** and then bind the same data again, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Please, provide a working example we can run. Also, I would not store address in that way, you are only loosing flexibility.

Comment: Just found out that the example I've given above is actually working. The problem is somewhere in my original code. Will see what I can do and post back here with the whole thing if necessary. As for the address - in my original post I have a datetime-column with 7 columns in it - the datenum-representation, year, month, day, .... The reason I did it like that is that I was unable to find a way to convert from datenum to string for later (found the solution later on) and I also find it easier if I am to assign some property based on hour-intervals (24h - morning,noon,afternoon,evening,night).

Comment: Splitting a column into several components is fine. I just advise to avoid nesting.

Comment: Here is why I'm doing that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347285/matlab-checking-if-a-given-date-hour-is-within-a-predefined-interval-with-date If you can give a heads up there I would gladly avoid such "dangerous" maneuvers. :) In my original code datetime is the only thing I'm nesting due to the reason described in the link above.