# Why does innerjoin fail when table contains a nested table in a variable

Tags: matlab

For example

```
tmp = table((1:10).'*2,(1:10).', table(ones(10, 5), ones(10, 1)))
tmp2 = table((1:10).')
```

Trying

```
innerjoin(tmp, tmp2)
```

gives

```
>> innerjoin(tmp, tmp2)
Error using table/innerjoin (line 83)
You cannot subscript a table using only one subscript. Table subscripting requires
both row and variable subscripts.
```

However

```
innerjoin(tmp(:, 1:2), tmp2)
```

is fine.

Comment: Interesting, lol. I'm guessing nested tables wasn't a usage case the authors of the join code had in mind :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found interesting your problem and still I'm not really good in MATLAB I tried to find some reasons for this error:

it's clearly that problem is because of addressing third column of table `tmp`. So I tried to watch function code:

```
edit innerjoin
```

error is here:

```
[c,il,ir] = table.joinInnerOuter(a,b,leftOuter,rightOuter,leftKeyVals,rightKeyVals, ...
                                 leftVars,rightVars,leftVarNames,rightVarNames);
```

Ok lets go deeper: watch inside this method:

in the moment of filling new table it use this function:

```
cvar_j = defaultarrayLike(szOut,'Like',leftvar_j);
```

and crash here at the step, when

```
leftvar_j = 

    Var1        Var2
____________    ____

[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1   
[1x5 double]    1
```

Last step: lets find WHY:
take a look at this `defaultarrayLike`:

```
if isfloat(x)
    y = nan(sz,'like',x);
elseif isnumeric(x)
    y = zeros(sz,'like',x);
elseif islogical(x)
    y = false(sz);
elseif ischar(x)
....
else
% *** this will fail if x is empty
y = x(1:0); y(n+1,p) = x(1); y = reshape(y(1:n,:),sz);
```

Here it is! It checks all datatypes for `x` and can't find table so goes to last `else` and try to address to `x(1:0)`, but we remember, that `x` is a table now and it needs more than one argument! What's why this crashes!

I tried to find the solution and find this theme:

[MATLAB error "You can not subscript a table using only one subscript error" when adding table in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345811/matlab-error-you-can-not-subscript-a-table-using-only-one-subscript-error-when)

It has no accepted answer, so your question is not duplicate, but it has some solution from OP! Try it!